# Como tratar valor e usar para determinada ação no CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou criando um sistema, no qual o usuário ao se cadastrar precisa ser verificado antes da liberação do acesso.

Tenho no banco o seguinte:

`use_status => 1;` Para usuários aprovados!
`use_status => 2;` Para usuários em análise!

Quero que enquanto status for 2, ele não consiga logar, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isto.

user_model:

```
public function login($email, $password) {
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->where('use_email', $email);
    $this->db->where('use_password', $password);
    $this->db->select("use_id");
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $query = $query->result();

    if ($query) {
        return $query[0]->use_id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function blockUser($status){
    $status = $this->db->select('use_status');

    if($status == 2){
        redirect('login/out');
    }
}
```

controller login:

```
public function in()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

        $login = $this->user_model->login($email, $password);
        $blockUser = $this->user_model->blockUser($status);


        if($login){

             $this->session->set_userdata('login', $login, $blockUser);

                $data = array(
                    'use_date_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'use_last_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
                );

                $this->user_model->update($data, $login);

                echo "login_success";

        }else{
            $this->session->set_userdata('login', false);

            echo "login_error";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, não vejo necessidade de usar dois métodos para isso, bastaria isso:

```
public function login($email, $password) {
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->where('use_email', $email);
    $this->db->where('use_password', $password);
    $this->db->where('use_status', 1);
    $this->db->select("use_id");
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $query = $query->result();

    if ($query) {
        return $query[0]->use_id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ou, se ainda preferir usar o `blockUser`, você precisa refazê-la, por que ela não está fazendo nada no momento, de onde veio o parâmetro `$status` que você passa pra dentro de `blockUser`? E perceba que por mais que você passe esse parâmetro pra dentro do método, lá você está sobrescrevendo seu valor, isso não faz muito sentido rsrs.